# SQL query to find out how much london store x customers also spend on coffee generally

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which shows customer orders

[image: customer id, store name, amount, type of order.]

Want to query it to find out how much in total did shoppers at beck's cake spend on using in-person order type in a wider/general sense.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: apologies sir/madam

Comment: No problem, just remember it the next time you ask a question.

Comment: What does your title have to do with the question?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? To me, it looks not that hard to use `SUM`

Answer (score 0):

If You want total sum of amount then please try below code..

```
    Select customerId,sum(amount) From TableName Where storename = "Beck's cakes" and OrderType = "in-person" Group By  customerId
```

Comment: So actually wanted to know. How much in total did shoppers at beck's cake spend on using in-person order type in a wider/general sense. To expand further people that shop at beck's cake can also shop at another store using order-type:over-the-phone. So wanted to know how many of beck's cake custoemrs spent in total using the over-the-phone method

Comment: Can you please provide samples of illustration like how you want data as a result.. it would be good to understand.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it seems, You need below -

```
SELECT customerId, SUM(AMOUNT) TOTAL_SPENT, SUM(CASE WHEN OrderType = 'over-the-phone' THEN amount END) OVER_THE_PHONE_SPENT
FROM TableName
WHERE customerId IN (SELECT customerId
                     FROM TableName
                     WHERE UPPER(storename) = "BECK'S CAKES"
                     AND UPPER(OrderType) = 'IN-PERSON')
GROUP BY customerId
```

Answer (score -1):

`SELECT SUM(amount) FROM screenshotted_table WHERE 'order type' = 'in-person' and 'store name' = 'Beck's cafe' GROUP BY 'customer id'`?

Comment: So actually wanted to know. How much in total did shoppers at beck's cake spend on using in-person order type in a wider/general sense. To expand further people that shop at beck's cake can also shop at another store using order-type:over-the-phone. So wanted to know how many of beck's cake custoemrs spent in total using the over-the-phone method.

Comment: So you want to track down Beck's Cake in-person customers and see what they spent in EVERY other shop? Do you want a total, customer by customer? Like, "*Timmy, who once bought in-person at Beck's Cake, spent a total of 400£ in other shops*"

Comment: I want 1 number. Total spent. How much did people that shopped at beck's cake also spent (when they used the in-person method). This number should include beck's total spent using the in person and overall. But overall could also include customers who never shopped at Beck's cake in their history. We don't want these in our total. Like "Timmy, once brought in-person at Beck's, Irish cafe and spent a total of 100 as total". This will be in the sum. "James, brought 5 times at irish cafe, student libary and ben's sportwear". This will not be in our sum because he never shopped at beck's at all.

Comment: What a minute, you want to see how much Beck's customers spent in all the shops but "*also include customers who never shopped at Beck's cake in their history*"? This makes no sense. Please, try to explain it again, and as others said, edit the question with result example

Comment: Like "Timmy, once brought in-person at Beck's, Irish cafe and spent a total of 100 as total". This will be in the sum. "James, brought 5 times at irish cafe, student libary and ben's sportwear". This will not be in our sum because he never shopped at beck's at all.

Comment: Can you please provide what output you actually need it is little confusing , In that case what you need is just  Select sum(amount) from your_table where 'order-type' ='in-person'